# Mapping JoinedSubclassMapping

Tags: c#, hibernate, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm getting this error when i try to insert into PurchaseCredit:

SQL logic error or missing database
foreign key mismatch - "PurchaseCredit" referencing "Deposit"

This is a part of the generated SQL:

```
create table FinancialDeposit 
(
    Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
    Version BIGINT not null,
    DatePayment date,
    Total money,
    Status INT,
)

create table Deposit 
(
    FinancialDepositId BIGINT not null unique,
    AccountId BIGINT not null,
    PersonName varchar(250) not null,
    primary key (FinancialDepositId),
    constraint FK737CDD9090887321 foreign key (AccountId) references Account,
    constraint FinancialDepositFK foreign key (FinancialDepositId) references FinancialDeposit
)

create table PurchaseCredit 
(
    Id  integer primary key autoincrement,
    Version BIGINT not null,
    PurchaseCode UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null unique,
    DepositId BIGINT,
    Total money,
    constraint FK737CDB4BFA0E8716 foreign key (DepositId) references Deposit
)
```

And this is a part of the C# code:

```
public class FinancialDepositMap : ClassMapping<FinancialDeposit>
{
    public FinancialDepositMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.DatePayment, map => map.Column(a => a.SqlType("date")));
        Property(x => x.Total);
        Property(x => x.Status);
        Property(x => x.DatePayment);
        Property(x => x.Hash);
    }
}

public class DepositMap : JoinedSubclassMapping<Deposit>
{
    public DepositMap()
    {
        ManyToOne(x => x.AccountId, m => m.NotNullable(true));
        Property(x => x.PersonName, m => m.NotNullable(true));
    }
}

public class PurchaseCreditMap : ClassMapping<PurchaseCredit>
{
    public PurchaseCreditMap()
    {
        Property(x => x.PurchaseCode, map =>
        {
            map.Unique(true);
            map.NotNullable(true);
            map.Update(false);
        });

        ManyToOne(x => x.Deposit);
        Property(x => x.Total);
    }
}
```

How can i map the column "Deposit" from "PurchaseCreditMap" to get this SQL:

```
create table PurchaseCredit 
(
    ...
    constraint FK737CDB4BFA0E8716 foreign key (DepositId) references Deposit (FinancialDepositId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any keys or Ids defined in your mappings.

See [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html) for inheritance mappings in mapping-by-code